# Display contents of child tags in contentful api

Tags: json, contentful

I am new to contentful api. I have created link tags when i enter a url for retrieving a level 0 tag entry (a content type). I am getting the child elements id

```
fields": {
"level0Tag": "Problem Solving",
"level1ChildTags": [
  {
    "sys": {
      "type": "Link",
      "linkType": "Entry",
      "id": "4uKXvRK0veAoEuk2yAuQ2Y"
    }
  },
  {
    "sys": {
      "type": "Link",
      "linkType": "Entry",
      "id": "3QMVgykrBey8KQ2SOw8CU6"
    }
  }
],
"displayChildTags": true
```

i wish to get the name field of level 1 child tags how to get it?

Comment: I can't see a `name` field here; is my sight still intact?

Comment: Is this a question asking how to parse the json string? If yes, what language are you working with?

Comment: no actually level1childtags which is linked with level0tag got name as a field currently i am getting only its id how to get that particular field

Comment: Actually i am using contentful api which is configured such that level0tag has relevant content of level1childtag i am currently getting only its id how to get the field name contained in level1tag

Comment: So what you mean is that the JSON string should contain a `name` tag and not just id, type and linkType? Do I understand your question correctly please?

Comment: i mean making use of the id it should fetch me all the contents of that tag actually this question has notting to do with json it is about configuring contentful api a online c.m.s application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you retrieve linked entries or assets, what you get is this object with a sys property which contains metadata relative to the kind of link (in your case it tells you it's an Entry and it contains the ID). Also, at the top level of the JSON response you should get an "includes" property with an array which contains all linked assets.

By default, the API resolves the links for 1 level. If you want more than one level (or none) you can use the "include" query string parameter (such as include=2).

If you use one of the SDKs, such as the Javascript SDK, they take care of resolving these links for you in the response and replacing them with the actual object, but by default the REST API doesn't do this.

Be aware as well, that this only happens when you query a collections endpoint, such as `/entries`, and not for single item endpoints such as `/entries/id`.

For more information check https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/ and https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/entries/entry/query-entries?console=1

Comment: I am making a request like this "http://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/j0llyl4oaod7/entries/4hKRSqsXk4gwKgAgaC8SeS?access_token=<auth token>&include=10"

And when I do this it does NOT resolve the referenced links in the resulting object, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the page below, you can specify a level with the `include` request parameter  to get the linked entries or assets in the response to a query and then you'll find the linked entries and assets in the `includes.Entry` and `includes.Asset` property of the response.

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/

If you happen to be using the JavaScript SDK that will allow to actually navigate the relationship graph transparently as you would expect (replace the link with the actual included resource).

https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js

Answer (score 0):

I tried initially using `getEntry` but as the docs say, this won't load linked content. Here's what I used instead:

```
function getOneNewsItemFromCMS(uid, callback) {
    // Using getEntries rather than getEntry ensures that we get linked items too
    client().getEntries({ 'sys.id': uid })
        .then(function (entries) {
            const item = processContentfulNewsItems(entries.items)[0];
            callback(item);
        });
}
```

The function `processContentfulNewsItems` maps the JSON format returned by Contentful to one expected by my React objects.